# Is there a way to detect available applications to pick image like gallery , amazon photos , google photos ... using flutter image picker

Tags: flutter, image, imagepicker

I want to create an image picker like android native that detect all available applications to pick image using flutter image picker.
To be more specific I want to display the available image applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Don't know about `image_picker`, but `file_picker` works for me as below

```
Future getFromGallery() async {
    FilePickerResult? result =
        await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.image);

    if (result != null) {
      setState(() {
        pickedImage = File(result.files.single.path!);
      });
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: exactly what I need thanks

Comment: @OussamaRidéne this is supported for both Android and iOS or this works only in android?

Comment: it support both android and ios

Comment: @Ruchit i have checked with above code but it's not worked on iOS for me is there any configuration to do in iOS?

Comment: have you completed the ios setup? https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/Setup#ios

Comment: @Ruchit Yes i have already did it but still it's open default album app of iPhone and not asking for all the apps like google photos

Comment: @Ruchit i have checked it's working on android but not on iOS do you have any idea about this?

Comment: i think ios is restricting it

Comment: @Ruchit An other plugin which provide same functionality any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243646/discussion-between-ruchit-and-vishal-parmar).

Comment: It' works for me on andoird and IOS  , and for ios I just add this code in Info.plist : <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>I need Access to User's Gallery</string>